# Need help excluding certain things from my array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I need to output stalls which made profit (if they made profit) in increasing order of profit (lowest profit to highest profit). When I run my program, it outputs it in increasing order but only excludes one instance of profit that is < 0 and outputs the rest. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the code I'm using to exclude stalls that made a profit of < 0

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (Stalls[i].net < 0){
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j){
            Stalls[j - 1] = Stalls[j];}
            n--;}

}

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (Stalls[i].net > Stalls[j].net) {
                Stall tmp = Stalls[i];
                Stalls[i] = Stalls[j];
                Stalls[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        of << Stalls[i].name << endl;
```

Comment: What is `Stalls`?  Why aren't you using standard containers and algorithms?

Comment: are you allowed to test for money-losing stalls earlier and not put them into the array in the first place?

Comment: Stalls is an array of structs. And also because I wasn’t allowed to use those for my assignment.

Comment: Split the problem in half: there is sorting, and there is output with a filter.  Can you write code for either or both of those things by itself?  I.e. can you write a loop which outputs the profitable stalls only, without sorting them?

Comment: Yes, I do have code to output the stalls without sorting. However the problem starts when I try to sort it

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not complete answer, but I found the main problem on the code.

```
# Remove negative items
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (Stalls[i].net < 0)
    {
        printf(" i = %d, %d\n", i, Stalls[i].net);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
        {
            // strcpy(Stalls[j - 1].name, Stalls[j].name);
            // Stalls[j - 1].net = Stalls[j].net;
            Stalls[j - 1] = Stalls[j];
        }
        n--;
    }
}
```

This function have problem

If `data` is `[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]`
After above `for` loop, `data` is `[-2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]`
But, we can think, the `data` is `[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]`

**Why:**
-3 -2 -1 0 1 2

The index of `-3` is 0,
With `Stalls[j - 1] = Stalls[j];`, `-3` is replace with `-2`,
and `-2` move to 0th position,

But, `-2` cannot check with `if (Stalls[i].net < 0)`, because the `i` is already increased

So, the `-2` is remain

**Easily answer:** (Not optimized)

```
// Remove negative items
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) // This is added loop
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (Stalls[i].net < 0)
        {
            printf(" i = %d, %d\n", i, Stalls[i].net);
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
            {
                // strcpy(Stalls[j - 1].name, Stalls[j].name);
                // Stalls[j - 1].net = Stalls[j].net;
                Stalls[j - 1] = Stalls[j];
            }
            n--;
        }
    }
```